# Restricting the letters used in a numbering generated by a xalan transformation

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I am looking for a way to not have some letters in the numbering of chapters generated by xalan in an .xml to .fo transformation.
I am using org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl to transform an .xml file into an .fo file to later make a PDF out of it. In the xml file I have some numbered chapters like so :

```
<prcitem2 numbering="9">
```

They are transformed in the .fo like so :
(This block is inside an fo:list-item-label, inside an fo:list-item, but I am on mobile and can't edit it properly. Sorry)

```
<fo:block>Й.</fo:block>
```

The xsl in charge of the transformation is :

```
<xsl:when test="ancestor-or-self::prcitem2">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="($language = 'ru')">
<xsl:number count="prcitem2" format="А."/>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

But my Russian comrades have informed me that some of their letters can't be used in numbering as it is not allowed by ATA and Russian standards  (e.g. Й, З (that's not a 3) and some others).
Is there a way to forbid the use of these letters ?

Comment: Consider to show the relevant XSLT code as well, so far it is not clear how the mapping is implemented or how the input snippet with `numbering="9"` relates to a FO snippet having a cyrillic letter.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this beautiful mess that is xslt. I'll try to find in my 8 thousand lines long xsl file what is in charge of the transformation.

Comment: I found the xsl ! And with my whole two hours of experience I would say that this looks like some work for an overriding of Xalan, but I could be wrong.

Comment: So Xalan XSLTC when counting some elements with `<xsl:number count="prcitem2" format="А."/>` spews out cyrillic letters like `Й.`? There is not even a `lang` attribute used on the `xsl:number` element. Can you try to isolate that to minumum samples of XML, XSLT and Java code and version to allow reproducing that? And what is the result you want instead? How do Russian ordinal numbers look?

Comment: There is indeed no lang attribute, so it is highly probable that we have somewhere some java override of xalan that does this. The comrades want to skip the forbidden letters and just display the next one. I will extract the xml xslt and java for those who want to reproduce this.

Comment: @MartinHonnen It's a Cyrillic `A`, not Latin `A`.

Comment: @MartinFouks Do you have a "map" of which character (or string) goes with which number?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I couldn't find a map in the xslt.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have found several xalan classes savagely imported in the project (the .java are dropped in it). I will check these first before I make an usable example. Thanks for your enthusiasm on my issue.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, good point, hadn't spot that. So we need someone to explain why the number 9 is formatted by Xalan (and Saxon when I try) from `<xsl:number count="prcitem2" format="А."/>` as `Й.` but doesn't seem to meet the expectactions of Russian natives. I am out of it, don't speak Russian.

Comment: до свидания. I don't speak Russian either ;) I'll update this when I find something.

Comment: @MartinFouks I wasn't asking about map in the XSLT. I meant what will be considered the correct result here? --- BTW, both Saxon and MSXML **do** skip `Й` (unlike Xalan) but all three output the number 8 as `З` (CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ZE) - so if this is incorrect, you will have to write your own algorithm.

Comment: They want to filter Ё З Й О Ч Ь Ы and Б and replace them with the next letter in the Russian alphabet. Thanks for your input. I'll look into that algorithm, but I wouldn't mind if someone would look into it too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, I don't see a way to "fix" the built-in `xsl:number` algorithm and I suggest you replace it with your own.

In the following template, replace the `alpha` parameter's value with the Cyrillic characters you want to use. Everything else is self-adjusting.

Note that the input numbering is expected to start at zero, so call the template with the `decimal` parameter's value being `= "$your-number - 1"`.

```
<xsl:template name="dec-to-alpha">
    <xsl:param name="decimal"/> 
    <xsl:param name="alpha" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="base" select="string-length($alpha)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="bit" select="$decimal mod $base"/>
    <xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($alpha, $bit + 1, 1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="next" select="floor($decimal div $base)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$next">
        <xsl:call-template name="dec-to-alpha">
            <xsl:with-param name="decimal" select="$next - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$char"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq74

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this tomorrow.